# Existence of a subcover with large boundary

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be a cover of $\mathbf{N}=\{1,2,\dotsc,N\}$ by finite subsets $S\in \mathscr{C}$ with $2\leq |S|\leq K$, where we write $|S|$ for the number of elements of $S$. Assume no element of $\mathbf{N}$ is contained in more than $K'$ elements of $\mathscr{C}$.

Given a subset $Z\subset \mathbf{N}$, we define the *boundary* $\partial Z$ of $Z$ to be the set of elements $n\in Z$ such that $n+1\not\in Z$. Assume that every $S\in \mathscr{C}$ satisfies $|\partial S|>|S|/2$.

Define a graph $\Gamma$ with elements of $\mathscr{C}$ as vertices, having an edge between $S,S'\in \mathscr{C}$ iff there are $n\in S$, $n'\in S'$ such that $n'\in \{n-1,n,n+1\}$.

Under what conditions is it the case that there must be a subset $\mathscr{D}\subset\mathscr{C}$ such that (a) the subgraph $\Gamma|_\mathscr{D}$ is connected and (b) the boundary of $\bigcup \mathscr{D}$ is large (meaning $\gg N$, say)?

(A satisfactory solution to the case $K'=1$ is given by [Existence of connected component with large boundary?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362168/existence-of-connected-component-with-large-boundary) In brief, it is then enough for every vertex of $\Gamma$ to have degree $\geq 3$. The condition can be easily relaxed: for $K'=1$, it is enough for $\Gamma$ to have many surviving vertices of degree $\geq 3$ after we repeatedly prune all vertices of degree $1$.)

Comment: One option is to simply work with the subgraph $\Gamma'\subset \Gamma$ having $\mathscr{C}$ as its set of vertices and an edge between $S$ and $S'$ only when there are $n\in S$, $n'\in S'$ such that $n' = n\pm 1$. Then one can try applying https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362168/existence-of-connected-component-with-large-boundary . Then one obtains $\mathscr{D}$ such that $\Gamma'|_\mathscr{D}$ (and hence $\Gamma|_\mathscr{D}$) is connected, and $\mathscr{D}$ has large boundary in $\Gamma'$. The problem is that that does not guarantee that $\partial(\bigcup \mathscr{D})$ is large.

Comment: I think you meant that no element of $\mathbf{N}$ is contained in more than $K'$ elements of $\mathscr{C}$ instead of "no element of $\mathbf{N}$ is contained in more than $K'$ elements of $\mathbf{N}$", right?

Comment: What is a precise definition of 'large boundary'? I mean what does $n$ in $>>n$ mean?

Comment: Edited, thanks.