# (Weakly) connected sets with large (out-)boundary

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory, trees, expander-graphs, spanning-tree

Let $\Gamma=(V,E)$ be a connected undirected graph with n vertices such that every vertex has degree at least $4$. Now draw arrows on some of the edges, in such a way that the in-degree of every vertex is $\geq 2$. It is allowed to draw arrows on both directions on an edge.

Must there be a connected subset $V'\subset V$ (that is, $\Gamma_{V'}$ is connected, as an undirected graph) having at least $\delta n$ elements in its outboundary?

(Feel free to define the outboundary of $V’$ either as the set of all $w$ not in $V’$ such that there exists an arrow from some vertex in $V’$ to $w$, or as the set of all $w$ in $V'$ such that there exists an arrow from $w$ to some vertex not in $V'$.)

Comment: For comparison, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362168/existence-of-connected-component-with-large-boundary

Comment: Do you mean "such that every vertex has **out-**degree 4"?

Comment: No, I meant that the in-degree plus the out-degree is 4 (as I say above).

Comment: OK, but then I am confused by the "at least" statement within the parenthesis. It seems to me that it should be removed, or is there something I misunderstand?

Comment: Ah, I should say "at least 4" both times. Edited.

Comment: Rewrote the question completely, for clarity.